# While Loops and Preventing duplicate information being looped through

Tags: php

I have a while loop that runs through a table collecting all rows that relate to a search term. The problem is there are multiple rows in my database that contain the exact same information so when the while loop runs through it will post duplicated information. I'm trying to find a way to prevent the while loop from showing the duplicated the situation. I was thinking of running an if statement around the echoed variable but I'm not sure what I would check to prevent duplicated information from showing. Here is the code below.

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT `primary_id`, `person_requested`, `likes` FROM 

`requests` WHERE `person_requested` LIKE '%$search_term%'");



while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)) 

{

$persons = $results_row['person_requested'];

echo $persons;  

}
```

Comment: do `distinct person_requested` in your query

Comment: You should solve it on the database layer using DISTINCT keyword. This is what it is for.

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: Table structure: http://i.imgur.com/VgfmU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` in your query to return distinct records:

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `person_requested`, `likes`
              FROM `requests` WHERE `person_requested` LIKE '%$search_term%'");
```

Comment: this might still return duplicate if person_requested has more than one row for different likes

Comment: Actually the likes are all the same but the primary_id is different for each one.

Comment: @jason328: what is your table structure?

Comment: I realized there is no reason for me to be calling up primary_id. Because the likes are the same for each row with the same person_requested in it the Distinct works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your SQL to only return the results you need. You can try using `DISTINCT` to eliminate duplicate results.